# How to query and extract specific markup from an html string using C# in server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-parsing

i have html string reside in files in the server and for each user request i have to select some markup with `ID` from mentioned files and send them to the client.i wonder, is there any library for .NET which can do this sort of job for me!?. what exactly i want to achieve is some thing like this (with Jquery):

```
var sometag = $("#id");
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).

> CsQuery is a jQuery port for .NET 4. It implements all CSS2 & CSS3 selectors, all the DOM manipulation methods of jQuery, and some of the utility methods. The majority of the jQuery test suite (as of 1.6.2) has been ported to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). I need 7 more characters to post.